# I forgot the index of my BIP32 key

Tags: address, bip32-hd-wallets

I had chosen at random an index for storing some bitcoins. My key derivation path is Bip32 m/0h/1

How would I go about generating all 2 billion keys and check which one has the funds I stored?

The bip32gen software is too slow for this to happen anytime soon.

Any ideas?

Comment: A modern multicore CPU with optimized EC code should be able to search those those in ~a day or so. Is that too slow?